# What types of security on server side should I use when I'm sending post data with jQuery's $.ajax()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

## Price estimation webapp

I'm writing simple price estimation webapp, which contains few slides with different options/parameters of desired product. As the user comes to my page, he goes through all my slides and selects which options/parameters he wants to be included. Selected options/parameters are stored by javascript in object.

On last slide I have email input with send button. In this input user writes his email adress and clicks on send button. Clicked send button has event listener which triggers jQuery $.ajax() function and sends options/parameters object with his email adress to mail.php

## PHP

mail.php script on server checks with array_key_exists(options/parameters). If true then it makes pdf file with selected options/parameters of product and sends it to user email adress.

## The problem - server security

The thing I'm worried about is **security of this process**. **Can you tell me possible vulnerability of this process and how to prevent it?**

Thank you

Comment: Require HTTPS, for one

Comment: I've forced HTTPS on all my sites. Still thanks for tip.

Comment: You might consider thinking about CSRF protection, since you are using jQuery, this gist might help you implement it https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3454607

Comment: If you are using a DB you shall use mysql_real_escape_string() function to avoid sql injection.